# Multi-Level Modelling: Do I have 2 levels or 3 levels?

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I have a question regarding multi-level modelling and whether this would be a 3 level.

I am conducting a tms study testing the effects of tms on face naming and tool naming.

Basically, each individual gets tms on three different brain sites. We measure the reaction times both pre tms and post tms.

Answer (score 1):

It would be three level.

1. Individual level
2. Brain sites level  (Brains sites nested to an individual)
3. Time level

You can use Proc mixed with double random statement in SAS.

Comment: To me it sounded like it is 1. time, 2. individual, 3. brain sites (the repeated measures are nested under individuals, who are nested within brain sites)

Comment: I think individual level is the highest level in the hierarchy. Each brain site is being measured twice for an individual.

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect054.htm  (example of doubly repeated measurements).

Comment: Aaaaaaaah, brain sites... never mind, I got it. TMS stands for transcranial magnetic simulation. When I hear sites in the context of MLM I immediately think of geographical locations. My mistake.